# Selenium: Timing inconsistency with WebDriverWait & click

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I have a set of divs to show/hide content in a typical accordion style. The HTML looks like this;

```
 <div class="accordionContainer">
    <div class="accordion">
      <h3>Click This</h3>
      <div class="accordionContent" style="display:none">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion">
      <h3>Click This</h3>
      <div class="accordionContent" style="display:none">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've then got my python to select that first H3 and then open a link that is in `accordionContent`.

```
 WebDriverWait(ff, 10).until(lambda driver : driver.find_element_by_xpath("id('main_content')/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/h3[1]")).click()

 WebDriverWait(ff, 10).until(lambda driver : driver.find_element_by_xpath("id('main_content')/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/p/a")).click()
```

I have ran this & seen it work. However most of the time it fails. The first div gets clicked (I can see a little arrow on it rotate to show the content but it seems to get clicked twice as it immediately returns to default and I get the error;

```
 [exec] selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: u'Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with'
```

Oddly though when it can be seen to be clicked, but not open, if you call the same click() line a second time it works.

Can that second xpath be advanced to check that the `accordionContent` has been changed to `display: block`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This xpath should work:

```
"//div[@class='accordionContainer']/div[@class='accordion'][1]/div[@class='accordionContent' and contains(@style, 'block')]"
```

or if the structure is pretty safe, could do:

```
"//div[@class='accordionContainer']/div[1]/div[contains(@style, 'block')]"
```

Note: I am assuming that it is just a typo in the example that the closing tag for the 'accordion' div is supposed to be a closing tag (rather than the opening tag seen).

Comment: They causes timeouts, but thanks - good to know you can `and` the parameters. I'm having to call the `click()` on the div twice to get it to open consistently. I can live with the way it works, but its strange that one needs to run twice to open the div - any ideas why that might happen?